# change url history at the GetJson

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

If my address is "http://localhost:8000/index", and I run this jquery:

```
 $.getJSON("1",function(data)
        {       
            .....code
        });
```

I get  "http://localhost:8000/index/1". That's great. But if I do if I wanted it to be :
"http://localhost:8000/1"
What do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the url root-relative:

```
$.getJSON("/1", function(data)
{
     .... code
});
```

Specifically, note the `/` at the start of the url. That is what will point it to the root of the current site, in this case: `http://localhost:8000/`